# unhandledRejection The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined - Nuxtjs

Tags: node.js, frontend, nuxt.js

When I try to build or run `nuxi dev` to start my application for development this error comes up and application don't work properly.
I deleted all lock files, removed module folder and run `yarn install` but this is still there,
This is the exception trace info from compiler.

```
  at readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
  at extractMeta (node_modules\nuxt-route-meta\dist\index.js:52:51)
  at parseRoutes (node_modules\nuxt-route-meta\dist\index.js:149:57)
  at /D:/Frontend/nuxt2/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:477:37
  at /D:/Frontend/nuxt2/node_modules/hookable/dist/index.mjs:39:70
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async Object.getContents (/D:/Frontend/nuxt2/node_modules/nuxt3/dist/chunks/index.mjs:348:9)
  at async /D:/Frontend/nuxt2/node_modules/nuxt3/dist/chunks/index.mjs:1338:22
  at async Promise.all (index 16)
```

Here is the .env file

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
ECHO_PORT=
HOSTNAME=http://localhost:3000
STRIPE_KEY=x
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=y
ALGOLIA_API_KEY=z
```

And here is the **nuxt.config.ts** file content.

```
import getSiteMeta from './utils/getSiteMeta'
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'

const meta = getSiteMeta()
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({

  ssr: false,

  // server: {
  //   host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost' // default: localhost
  // },

  sitemap: [
    {
      hostname: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
      path: '/sitemap.xml',
      gzip: true,
    },
  ],

// Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en-GB',
    },
    title:
      'Family Tree 365 - Start your family tree today - free! Your first tree is 100% free. Sign-up to begin your genealogy journey today!',
    meta: [
      ...meta,
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'HandheldFriendly', content: 'True' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { property: 'og:site_name', content: 'Family Tree 365' },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content:
          'Our user-friendly yet powerful platform lets you create your own family tree the quick and easy way. No technical knowledge is required. Start your family tree today - free!',
      },
      { property: 'og:image:width', content: '2500' },
      { property: 'og:image:height', content: '780' },
      { name: 'twitter:site', content: '@familytree365' },
      { name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary_large_image' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        hid: 'canonical',
        rel: 'canonical',
        href: process.env.BASE_URL,
      },
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  // css: ["~/assets/style/enso.scss", "animate.css/animate.compat.css"],
  css: [
    'animate.css/animate.compat.css',
    '~/assets/css/base.css',
    '~/assets/style/enso.scss',
    '~/assets/css/fontawesome.min.css',
  ],

  router: {
    middleware: 'auth'
  },

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/bootEnums.js',
    '~/plugins/i18n.js',
    '~/plugins/pRoute.js',
    '~/plugins/filters.js',
    '~/plugins/numberFormat.js',
    '~/plugins/shortNumber.js',
    '~/plugins/toastr.js',
    '~/plugins/fontawesome.js',
    '~/plugins/themesSettingRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/bookmarksSettingRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/tutorialSettingRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/notificationsRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/localisationRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/ioRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/tasksNavbarRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/usersRegister.js',
    '~/plugins/Validator.js',
    '~/plugins/date-fns/format.js',
    '~/plugins/date-fns/formatDistance.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-select.js',
    '~/plugins/vuelidate.js',
    '~/plugins/vue-gtag.client.js',
    //'~/plugins/echo.js',
    "~/plugins/vue-fb-customer-chat.js",
    {src: '~/plugins/vue-stripe.js', ssr: false},
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  // components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    // "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
    '@nuxtjs/router-extras',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'nuxt-vuex-router-sync',
    'nuxt-route-meta',
  ],

  fontawesome: {
    icons: {
      solid: true,
      brands: true,
    },
  },
  nuxtContentAlgolia: {
    appId: process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    apiKey: process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY,
    paths: [
      {
        name: 'articles',
        index: 'articles',
        fields: ['title', 'description', 'bodyPlainText'],
      },
    ],
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      browserBaseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
      proxyHeaders: false,
    },
    appEnv: process.env.APP_ENV || 'production',
    },

  env: {
    STRIPE_PK: process.env.STRIPE_KEY,
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL ||'http://localhost:3000',
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    proxyHeaders: false,
    proxy: true,
    credentials: true,
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8000',
    '/broadcasting/': process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8000',
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    filenames: {
      app: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : '[chunkhash].js'),
      chunk: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : '[chunkhash].js'),
      css: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[name].css' : '[contenthash].css'),
      img: ({ isDev }) => (isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'img/[hash:7].[ext]'),
      font: ({ isDev }) =>
        isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'fonts/[hash:7].[ext]',
      video: ({ isDev }) =>
        isDev ? '[path][name].[ext]' : 'videos/[hash:7].[ext]',
    },

    transpile: [
      '@enso-ui/strings',
      'vee-validate/dist/rules',
      '@enso-ui/enums',
      '@sentry/browser',
      '@sentry/integrations',
      '@enso-ui/sentry',
      '@enso-ui/route-mapper',
      'd3-dag',
    ],

    extend(config) {
      const isScssRule = (rule) => rule.test.toString() === '/\\.scss$/i'

      config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
        if (isScssRule(rule)) {
          const normalRule = rule.oneOf.find(
            ({ resourceQuery, test }) =>
              resourceQuery === undefined && test === undefined
          )

          const lazyRule = cloneDeep(normalRule)

          lazyRule.test = /\.lazy\.scss$/
          const idx = lazyRule.use.findIndex(({ loader }) =>
            loader.includes('vue-style-loader')
          )
          if (idx > -1) {
            lazyRule.use.splice(idx, 1, {
              loader: 'style-loader',
              options: {
                injectType: 'lazyStyleTag',
                insert: function insertAtTop(element) {
                  const parent = document.querySelector('head')
                  parent.insertBefore(element, parent.firstChild)
                },
              },
            })
          }

          rule.oneOf.push(lazyRule)
        }
      })

      // const scssRules = config.module.rules.find('scss').oneOfs;
      // const normalRule = scssRules.store.get('normal');
      // const lazyRule = config.module.rules.find('scss').oneOf('scss-lazy');

      // normalRule.uses.values().forEach(use => {
      //   if (use.name !== 'vue-style-loader') {
      //     lazyRule.use(use.name).merge(use.entries());
      //     return;
      //   }

      //   lazyRule.use('style-loader')
      //     .loader('style-loader')
      //     .options({
      //       injectType: 'lazyStyleTag',
      //       insert: function insertAtTop(element) {
      //         const parent = document.querySelector('head');
      //         parent.insertBefore(element, parent.firstChild);
      //       },
      //     });
      // });

      // lazyRule.test(/\.lazy\.scss$/);

      // scssRules.store.delete('normal', 'scss-lazy');
      // scssRules.store.set('scss-lazy', lazyRule);
      // scssRules.store.set('normal', normalRule);
    },
  },
})
```

Have a look at my package.json file

```json
 {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxi dev",
    "build": "nuxi build",
    "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    "nuxt3": "^3.0.0-27444169.120ee4f"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@enso-ui/bulma": "^5.0.7",
    "@enso-ui/charts": "^4.0.0",
    "@enso-ui/laravel-validation": "^2.0.6",
    "@enso-ui/transitions": "^2.0.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/router-extras": "^1.1.1",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "chart": "^0.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "nuxt-route-meta": "^2.3.4",
    "nuxt-vuex-router-sync": "^0.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "resolve": "1.20.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-gtag-next": "^1.14.0",
    "vue-loading-overlay": "5.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: More details on your configuration would be welcome.

Comment: this is my .env file 
```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:8000
ECHO_PORT=
HOSTNAME=http://localhost:3000
STRIPE_KEY=x
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=2R81LPS2AZ
ALGOLIA_API_KEY=4e36d72cdd3978ce8379a0502132ab03```

Comment: And here is my nuxt.config.ts file. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17vfDB7KrQFGwgnnU2fQS3Dpk_WafxSNh/view?usp=sharing @kissu

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting it in comments and via an external link.

Comment: @kissu I appreciate, I've edited the question. please have a look now.

Comment: AFAIK, `nuxi` is mainly for Nuxt3 projects while this one looks like it's Nuxt2. What do you have in your `package.json`?

Comment: @kissu This is a nuxt 3 project,  nuxt2 is the project directory.
It was nuxt 2 project was working perfect, but when upgraded to nuxt3 it is causing this issue.

Comment: If you want to upgrade from Nuxt2 to Nuxt3, you will need to apply several changes for a proper working migration. [Start here](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/bridge#upgrade-nuxt-2) and try to find the equivalent in Nuxt3.

Comment: I added package.json to the question you can have a look over that. 
I'm surprised why this is happening, which path I'm missing  in the env.

Comment: It's not a path in your code itself, it's an issue because of something not being supported by Nuxt3 that you still use (coming from Nuxt2). So, it's the path of the source code that is not understanding your nuxt configuration. For example, things like `ssr` do not exist anymore in Nuxt3 or any other breaking change really.